# How to fetch one single row of an excel sheet with Box\Spout

Tags: php, excel

I'm trying out Box\Spout and rewriting some code which was formerly using PHPExcel. Iterating through rows is clear but in a few cases I need to address directly one specific row. I cannot find this in the documentation.

Something like:

```
$row = $sheet->getRow(8);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't access rows directly. If you need the 8th row, you'll need to read the first 8 rows... This is because Spout does not load the entire spreadsheet in memory so it reads the data row by row.

However, you can do something like this:

```
foreach ($reader->getSheetIterator() as $sheet) {
    foreach ($sheet->getRowIterator() as $rowIndex => $row) {
        if ($rowIndex !== 8) {
            continue;
        }

        // do something with row 8
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought this much already, but I had to ask. While we're at it; can somebody add the tag 'spout', I don't have the privileges to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the iterator's `key()` method:

```
$it = $sheet->getRowIterator();
$row = $it->key(8);
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a try, I let you know.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. It returns the integer 0. Too bad.